# How do I specify type parameters as being function arguments in Rust?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to make a list that will hold `Box<dyn Fn(&E)>` where `E` is specified as part of the type. This works until `E` contains a reference, at which point it starts asking for lifetimes that aren't relevant.

A simpler example:

```rust
pub struct CallbackTest<E> {
    pub cb: Box<dyn Fn(&E)>,
}

impl<E> CallbackTest<E> {
    pub fn new<F>(cb: F) -> Self
    where
        F: Fn(&E)
    {
        Self { cb: Box::new(cb) }
    }
}

pub struct GameData { /* ... */ }

pub type TestRef = CallbackTest<(u32, &GameData)>;
```

This gives me a `missing lifetime specifier` error. I *could* put a lifetime parameter on `TestRef` to make it work, but that's not the correct lifetime. I don't want the `&GameData` to have to live for the entire lifetime of the `CallbackTest`, just during the function call.

EDIT: The &GameData is intentional. It's not a mistake. I hope my changes have made the goal behind this more obvious.

Any advice?

Comment: I don't know why, it does work with this way(https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=eb73d5779e9360acddf84b214cf70bdc) , but i doubt it is trustworthy

Comment: Why do you want two reference ? https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=943700d401b0dcc5624ad8cac4b2b8c9

Comment: As said by @Stargateur, I think that's due to the fact that you added mistakenly another reference layer to `u32`. In this situation, the compiler is right to ask for a lifetime.

Comment: The `&u32` was intentional. I've changed it to be a bit more explicit that I'm trying to pass a tuple with multiple values, one of which is a reference.

Comment: I'm afraid your edits have left this sentence somewhat ambiguous: *I don't want the `&u32` to have to live for the entire lifetime of the `CallbackTest`, just during the function call.* Does @ÖmerErden's suggestion work for you?

Comment: My bad, and no. The problem is seems to be that I can't make CallbackTest generic over the function argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here we are [rust.playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=09bc82f5578a0289e5deeba528b516c5)

```
use std::marker::PhantomData;

pub struct CallbackTest<'a, E, Fa: 'a + Fn(&E)> {
    pub cb: Box<Fa>,
    _e: &'a PhantomData<E>,
}

impl<'a, E, Fa: 'a + Fn(&E)> CallbackTest<'a, E, Fa> {
    pub fn new(cb: Fa) -> Self
    {
        Self { 
            cb: Box::new(cb), 
            _e: &PhantomData
        }
    }
}

pub struct GameData { 
    pub field: i32,
}

pub type TestRef<'a, 'b, Fb> = CallbackTest<'b, (u32, &'a GameData, ), Fb>;

fn main() {
    let game_data = GameData{ field: 42};
    let test_ref: TestRef<_> = CallbackTest::new(|(val, gd): &(u32, &GameData)| { println!("val:{}, field:{}", val, (*gd).field)});
    (test_ref.cb)(&(24, &game_data));
}
```